# removing html tags but keep the inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav menu which have a mega menu.It has several markup to make it a mega menu.But i want to remove some of the markups when in small viewport.

### So my markups are

```
<ul class="megamenu-wrapper">
 <li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Abort</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li> 
    <ul>   
        <li><a href="#">gang</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">food</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

### what i want

```
<ul class="megamenu-wrapper">

        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Abort</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">gang</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">food</a></li>

</ul>
```

`i have two mega-menu-wrapper`

### What i have tried

```
var megaContents = $('.megamenu-wrapper li ul').contents();
    $('.megamenu-wrapper li ul').replaceWith( megaContents );
```

It makes a same list in two each mega menu and in each megamenu there is about 5 times repetation of each elements.
Anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

*Use*

```
//Fimd child ul li and append it to main ul
$('.megamenu-wrapper > li > ul > li').appendTo('.megamenu-wrapper');

//Remove li having ul
$('.megamenu-wrapper > li:has(ul)').remove();;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.megamenu-wrapper > li > ul > li').appendTo('.megamenu-wrapper'); +
      $('.megamenu-wrapper > li:has(ul)').remove();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="megamenu-wrapper">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Abort</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">gang</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">food</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

use `.each()` if you have multiple menus

```
$('.megamenu-wrapper') each(function () {
    $(this).find('> li > ul > li').appendTo(this);
    $(this).find(' > li:has(ul)').remove();
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j8ze5vpa/)

Comment: @SumaiyaSalam, See example https://jsfiddle.net/j8ze5vpa/ I have also updated answer

Answer (score 0):

With your current markup, you can use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which will take the children `li` with anchors and append them as **direct** children of `.megamenu-wrapper`

Then, use [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove the former **parent** `li` elements which now contain empty `ul` children

```
$('.megamenu-wrapper').append($('li:has(a)'));
$('.megamenu-wrapper').children('li:has(ul)').remove();
```

**Update**

For multiple menus, you can use the snippet above, but wrap it in an [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) call

```
$('.megamenu-wrapper').each(function(){
    $(this).append($(this).find('li:has(a)'));
    $(this).children('li:has(ul)').remove();
});
```

```js
$('.megamenu-wrapper').each(function(){
$(this).append($(this).find('li:has(a)'));

$(this).children('li:has(ul)').remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="megamenu-wrapper">
 <li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Abort</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li> 
    <ul>   
        <li><a href="#">gang</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">food</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>

<ul class="megamenu-wrapper">
 <li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Abort</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li> 
    <ul>   
        <li><a href="#">gang</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">food</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but see if there is two same menu what happens : https://jsfiddle.net/kf7t99L2/1/

Comment: @SumaiyaSalam, sorry, my updated answer had an error. Now it is complete